# Java Applet AccessControlException

Tags: java, client-side, applet

I am doing a security course and a module on client side attacks, which is why this post might seem evil or outdated.

I have a Java applet fetching a malicious jar file and trying to then download and execute a malicious binary on a Windows 7 host.

When debugging the applet in Java Console I am getting the following error:

```
basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 186710 us, pluginInit dt 8044964 us, TotalTime: 8231674 us
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.io.tmpdir" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at Java.init(Java.java:19)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.init(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@1089de1
security: Reset deny session certificate store
```

I believe this corresponds with the below line of code:

```
String tmpdir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + File.separator;
```

The applet has been compiled as below...

```
/opt/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/javac Java.java
echo "Permissions: all-permissions" > /root/manifest.txt
/opt/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/jar cvfm Java.jar /root/manifest.txt Java.class 
keytool -genkey -alias signapplet -keystore mykeystore -keypass mykeypass -storepass password123
jarsigner -keystore mykeystore -storepass password123 -keypass password123 -signedjar SignedJava.jar Java.jar signapplet
```

I think the solution is something like that detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168312/use-applet-in-html) but I'm not sure what exactly to add to my code in order to bypass this restriction. I have `all-permissions` set in a manifest file on my local Kali box but I don't know enough about Java to know if this should or should not be fixing my error.

```
echo "Permissions: all-permissions" > /root/manifest.txt
```

What do I need to change to fix this exception and have my applet run?

Answer (score 0):

This exploit is totally broken as of today and no updates to the course materials whatsoever...

At least the official offsec forums provide some hints on how to get this working.

Some people say, it'll work, using an older **java** version (prior **1.8.0_144**).
Unfortunately this didn't work out for me.

So I had to try another "fix" to get it working: 
Adding `permission java.security.AllPermission;` to the `grant` section in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\security\java.policy` on the target box.

Unfortunately I totally dislike this workaround, as I feel the exploit to be worthless, when I have to modify the security settings on the target box in a way, I normally just can't do.

Hope this helps, anyway :-)